# RadPieChartView with DoughnutSeries rounding off values and total percentage is not matching with 100%

Tags: android, xamarin.android, telerik

I'm using Telerik chart controls.

I'm assigning values to DoughnutSeries and telerik is rounding off the percentage. After rounding off percentage DounutSeries total percenatage is not matching with 100%.

Please see the attachment.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, check [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure you will receive more attention.

Comment: Could you show me your code?

Comment: Please find my code below.

Comment: public static RadPieChartView CreateChart(Context activity, List<int> interTribeLeaderboard, List<SliceStyle> styles)
        {
            var pieChart = new RadPieChartView(activity);
            var doughnutSeries = new DoughnutSeries();
            doughnutSeries.ValueBinding = new ValueBinding();
            doughnutSeries.SliceStyles = styles;
            doughnutSeries.ShowLabels = true;
            doughnutSeries.Data = PopulateData(interTribeLeaderboard);
            pieChart.Series.Add(doughnutSeries);
            return pieChart;
        }

Comment: private static ArrayList PopulateData(List<int> interTribeLeaderboard)
        {
            ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
            foreach (var tribeValue in interTribeLeaderboard)
            {
                var entity = new DataEntity { Value = tribeValue };
                result.Add(entity);
            }

            return result;
        }

Comment: public class ValueBinding : DataPointBinding
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets the value.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="p0">The p0.</param>
            /// <returns>the value</returns>
            public override Java.Lang.Object GetValue(Java.Lang.Object p0)
            {
                var entity = (DataEntity)p0;
                return entity.Value;
            }
        }

Comment: public class DataEntity : Java.Lang.Object
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the value.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>
            /// The value.
            /// </value>
            public double Value { get; set; }
        }